# Show that the vector $v=A^T(y-Ax)$ has nonnegative entries where $x$ is the minimizer of $\|y-Ax\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ real matrix and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector with nonnegative entries that minimizes the Euclidean distance $\|y-Ax\|$ (among all nonnegative vectors $x$). Show that the vector $v=A^T(y-Ax)$ has nonnegative entries.

I've seen a solution that involves contradiction and a slight perturbation on $x$, but it doesn't really help with my intuition. Anything that would help build intuition would really help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is an optimization problem where the feasible set is the positive orthant in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align}
\min_x &\quad \frac{1}{2}\|y - Ax \|^2 \\
\text{such that} &\quad x \in \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^+.
\end{align}
The quantity $A^T(y-Ax)$ is the negative gradient of the objective function:
$$g = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2}\|y - Ax \|^2\right) = -A^T(y-Ax).$$

There are two possiblities:

1. The optimal point could lie in the interior of the feasible set. In that case the gradient is zero, so $-g$ is trivially non-negative.
2. The optimal point could lie on the boundary of the feasible set. Then the gradient is perpendicular to the feasible set, pointing outwards. Hence the quantity of interest, $-g$, points perpendicularly *inward* into the positive orthant, and therefore has entries that are either positive or zero.

[image: gradient perpendicular to feasible set]

For more details on this sort of reasoning look into [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) and the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for constrained optimization.